# Possible context of "underpinning"

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning-in-context, context

I wonder, if I might use the word:
'underpinning' in the context of technologies.

Looking for examples, I usually only find it in the context of
theories and arguments.

Example:
"MIMO is underpinning many modern technologies"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit off.  The usage you're trying to leverage is given by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underpinning) as

> something that serves as a foundation :  basis, support —often used in plural

which is taken by analogy from

> the material and construction (as a foundation) used for support of a structure

To my ear, that analogy is a bit off here. Much more common is something like

> MIMO enables many modern technologies.

or

> MIMO is the basis of many modern technologies.

or

> MIMO is at the heart of many modern technologies.

IMHO, the first is the most appropriate for MIMO.